# using traits inside laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, vuejs2

I have some repetitive codes inside my laravel(7.23.0)controller

```
use App\ModelA;
use App\ModelB;
use App\ModelC;
use App\Traits\DbTrait;

    class DarsController extends Controller
    {
       use DbTrait;

    public function A($id) {
           return ModelA::where('column', $id)->get(*);
    }
    public function B($id) {
           return ModelB::where('column', $id)->get(*);
    }

    public function C($id){
           return ModelC::where('column', $id)->get(*);
      }
    //the only difference in these codes is model, all codes are the same
    
  }
```

I had created a folder named Traits and inside that I had defined a trait DbTrait.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Traits;

trait DbTrait
{
    public function getAllz($ModelName , $id){
        return $ModelName::where('column', $id)->get('*');
    }
}
```

so I modified my controller's functions to this

```
public function A($id) {
            //   return ModelA::where('column', $id)->get(*); works fine
               $this->getAllz('ModelA', $id);// throws an error

   }
```

it throws an error message: "Class 'ModelA' not found"

thank you

**update:
i should apologize, i am really sorry, 3 of the answer worked, and i see the data inside network tab,i am using vue to display data,
and i think using trait made a complex array**

this is my simple vue

```
axios.get('/api/emla/' + id).then(response =>{
                         this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)); 
}
```

Comment: because it's looking for `ModelA` class in your traits directory

Comment: `app( '\App\' . $ModelName )::where('column', $id)->get('*');`

Comment: thanks @swadha may i ask you to elaborate, i couldnt just copy and paste your code

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not use the full class name (including the namespace)?

Comment: @Nico how? sorry I am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify your trait

`ModelName::where` it try to load the class in trait so use `$ModelName->where` here `$ModelName` is already instance of that class so you can call function via `->` operator

```php
<?php 
namespace App\Traits;

trait DbTrait
{
    public function getAllz($ModelName ,$columnName ,$id){
        return $ModelName->where($columnName, $id)->get('*');
    }
}
```

and to call this function

```php
$this->getAllz(new ModelA, $id);
```

this way you don't need to import class inside trait

your final code will be like this

```php
use App\ModelA;
use App\ModelB;
use App\ModelC;
use App\Traits\DbTrait;

class DarsController extends Controller
{
    use DbTrait;

    public function A($id)
    {
        return $this->getAllz(new ModelA,'column', $id);
    }
    public function B($id)
    {
        return $this->getAllz(new ModelB,'column', $id);
    }

    public function C($id)
    {
        return $this->getAllz(new ModelC,'column', $id);
    }
}
```

Comment: @thanks kamlesh, I edited question because of typo, sorry about that, I tried, but it gives me a message 'this request has no response data available'

Comment: @raamiin what you have tried and what error you getting .?

Comment: everything, your answer,it didnt give me the data from database so i inspect  in google dev tools inside network tab

Comment: @raamiin becouse all model is lookning for `dars_id` column as you write in  code

Comment: i tried this answer carefully, error changed back to "Class 'ModelA' not found"

Comment: @raamiin line number ?

Comment: trace: [{function: "A", class: "App\Http\Controllers\DarsController", type: "->"},…],, $this->getAllz(new $model, 'column', $id); // i used appropriate word for column

Comment: remove  `$` from `model` from  `$this->getAllz(new ModelA, 'column', $id)`

Comment: thank you so much but 'message 'this request has no response data available'

Comment: @raamiin then check with `dd()` what data your getting or model instance getting or not

Comment: "Call to a member function where() on string"   //return $ModelName->where($columnName, $id)->get('*');// when i use new keyword cant find class name ModelA

Comment: `getAllz(new ModelA, 'column', $id)` here 1st parameter is not string it is `instnace of `ModelA` by new keyword then inside trait `where()` will work

Comment: i edited parameter and i  dd($this->getAllz(new ModelA(), 'dars_id', $id)); i can see data in network(preview) tab

Answer (score 0):

Import the classes which will be used in your trait as you have done in the controller class.

```
use App\ModelA;
use App\ModelB;
use App\ModelC;
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason you're getting `Class 'ModelA' not found` is because it's looking for that class in your traits directory, which it won't find. so you need this instead:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Traits;

trait DbTrait
{
    public function getAllz($ModelName , $id) {
        return app( "\App\\" . $ModelName )::where('column', $id)->get('*');
    }
}
```

assuming that you've defined your models under `\App` namespace

Comment: @thanks swadhwa I didn't change the directory of Models in the first place(it is in the default directory), i am using visual studio code, I pasted your code, it says expecting ')', I am a noob

Comment: message: "Target class [\App\{ModelA}] does not exist."

Comment: @raamiin ah crap I forgot to escape backslash. can you check now. sorry.

Comment: thanks but  'this request has no response data available'

Comment: @raamiin that seems like an unrelated issue. I've provided you with the solution. Please accept this and post a new question and I'll look into that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

100% should work if you follow this

```
public function A($id) {
        //   return ModelA::where('column', $id)->get(*); works fine
           $model = new ModelName(); // new ModelName;
           $this->getAllz($model, $id);// throws an error

}


public function getAllz($ModelName , $id){
    return $ModelName->where('column', $id)->get('*');
}
```

Comment: thanks Ripon when I dd( $this->getAllz($model, $id)); i can see data in network tab, but i can't get what i want

Comment: nothing return from method A . that's why you are not getting the expected result. i think